# How to develop GTK+ programs on windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, gtk

There isn't a windows binary release, so when it says that they are cross-OS, they mean you can write source to compile on windows, but you have to develop in linux/osx? But then what if you want to make calls to win32api within the app, and want to test as you go along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean you can develop under Windows and you do not have to compile the libraries for yourself.
Binaries for GTK+ and its dependencies can be found [here](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php).

Cross OS means that the same API is available across all supported platforms.

Direct calls to the win32 API can be made normally in a GTK+ application.

Comment: Note that official Windows binaries are only provided for GTK 2, which is no longer maintained.